# Do I have to install wxPython on another PC in order to run it on that PC?

Tags: wxpython

I don't want to have to install it on another PC just to run it on that one. Is there another way to run it on another PC without installing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bundle your application into an executable using, say, [`PyInstaller`](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (Windows, Linux, and some OSX support), [`py2app`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) (OSX), or [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/) (Windows).

There are a bunch of differences between these, so you'll need to look into them more if this is the type of solution you'd like to pursue.

Comment: Does that mean that when I use these programs, it won't show the source code?

Comment: I didn't, I guess someone else did.  It seems like a good question to me, which is why I answered it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks. Can you give it an up vote, because if I keep getting down votes then I won't be able to ask more questions?

Comment: Thank you. :) Do you think I should use wxPython for general purpose programming?

Comment: Happy to help, and good luck with SO.  (In general, "which tools/software to use" questions and discussions are really disliked on SO, and although I don't like this rule, I'd recommend sticking to it or you'll get lots of hate and downvotes.  People ask this qui preference question a lot so you can find discussions elsewhere, eg, reddit/Python, Python forums, and elsewhere.  But briefly..)  I use wxPython for general purpose programming and I like it.  PyQT is the other main competitor, and is really worth a look to see which is better for your specific case.

Comment: I installed PyInstaller, opened PythonWin. How do I get the .py file into an exe?

Comment: In general on SO, it's best to keep discussion directly related to clarifying the answer to the specific question (and not as a launching point to a full tutorial).  I suggest starting with the PyInstaller documentation, and then ask another question if you get stuck.  As a place to start, see http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html#getting-started

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this sort of thing. One of the simplest would be to use Portable Python. It includes wxPython and lots of other goodies. You can get it here: http://portablepython.com/

Of course if you went that route, then you would have to share your source files. If you don't want to do that, then you might want to look at the following:

- py2exe (old, but well documented) - Windows only
- PyInstaller - works on Mac, Windows, Linux, etc
- cx_freeze - cross platform
- bbfreeze
- py2app - Mac only

However, I think my favorite is GUI2Exe which is a nice GUI around all of these and makes creating an exe very easy. You can check it out here: http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/

I also wrote tutorials on all these except for py2app. You can read about them at the following links:

- GUI2Exe - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/31/another-gui2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/
- bbfreeze - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/19/a-bbfreeze-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/
- cx_freeze - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/12/a-cx_freeze-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/
- pyInstaller - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/10/a-pyinstaller-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/
- py2exe - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/31/a-py2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

You might also find this article interesting in which I describe how bundle up my exe into an installer using Inno Setup: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/08/27/packaging-wxpymail-for-distribution/

Comment: How do I do it with the py2exe that comes with Portable Python?

Comment: I don't think you can. Just use it with your Python. That should work fine.